# Efficient way of blocking / denying nginx connections via IP

Tags: nginx

I would like to filter several different endpoints by IP using nginx. My current solution is to cut and paste the following code for each endpoint:

```
    location /api0 {
        allow 123.45.67.89; 
        allow 98.765.43.21; 
        deny all;
        ......
    }

    location /api1 {
        allow 123.45.67.89; 
        allow 98.765.43.21; 
        deny all;
        ......
    }

    etc
```

Is there a more efficient way of setting up these IP filters? Is it possible to setup a group so I can use that for all the endpoints in the config file?

My main issue here is that sometimes an IP address needs to be changed, which means I have to manually cut & paste the IP and then restart nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `include` directory. Create a file `allowlist.conf` and add `allow` directives in there:

```
allow 123.45.67.89; 
allow 98.765.43.21;
```

Now you can include the content of that file multiple times in the nginx config.

```
    location /api0 {
        include allowlist.conf;
        deny all;
        ......
    }

    location /api1 {
        include allowlist.conf;
        deny all;
        ......
    }

    etc
```

*Source: https://blackfedora.dev/nginx-restricting-access-based-on-ip-address*